# Web server not available on Debian virtual machine

Tags: apache-2.2, php, xdebug

I have set up a virtual debian machine that I am running on my windows box (using VirtualBox) for a development LAMP stack.  Today when I try to load up a dev website from my windows machine the browser isn't getting a response from my VM.  I'm not much of a linux admin; here's what i can tell you:

1. The browser never gets a response, but it doesn't get any 500 errors either.  It just sits spinning its wheels..
2. Yesterday I did some work on the VM to build the php imagick.so executable so I could work with some pdf editing libraries.  The changes were (ultimately) basically these:

   - $ apt-get update php5-devel
   - $ apt-get update make
   - $ apt-get install php-pear
   - $ apt-get install libmagickwand-dev
   - $ pecl install imagick
3. Before I made those changes, I made a snapshot of my working VM.  When I ran into this problem, I shut down my modified VM and started up my earlier snapshot.  This makes no difference - same web server problem.
4. From my windows machine I can ping my VM at the expected ip (192.168.1.222)
5. However, I *cannot* ping port 80.  I get a "could not find host 192.168.1.222:80 response.
6. Previously I was able to restart apache without any apparent problems, but a moment ago when I did /etc/init.d/apache2 stop then start, I got this for the first time:

**Edit: updated question after restarting apache as root**

**Stopping/starting server:**

```
root@debian:/home/brd# /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
Stopping web server: apache2 ... waiting .
root@debian:/home/brd# /etc/init.d/apache2 start
Starting web server: apache2.
```

Apache seems to restart without complaint

```
root@debian:/home/brd# tail /var/log/apache2/error.log
Failed loading /usr/lib/php5# ls 20090626+lfs/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php5# ls 20090626+lfs/xdebug.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed loading /usr/lib/php5# ls 20090626+lfs/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php5# ls 20090626+lfs/xdebug.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[Thu Mar 14 09:27:16 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
Failed loading /usr/lib/php5# ls 20090626+lfs/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php5# ls 20090626+lfs/xdebug.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[Thu Mar 14 09:27:22 2013] [error] python_init: Python version mismatch, expected '2.6.5+', found '2.6.6'.
[Thu Mar 14 09:27:22 2013] [error] python_init: Python executable found '/usr/bin/python'.
[Thu Mar 14 09:27:22 2013] [error] python_init: Python path being used '/usr/lib/python2.6/:/usr/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2:/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-tk:/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-old:/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload'.
[Thu Mar 14 09:27:22 2013] [notice] mod_python: Creating 8 session mutexes based on 150 max processes and 0 max threads.
[Thu Mar 14 09:27:22 2013] [notice] mod_python: using mutex_directory /tmp
[Thu Mar 14 09:27:22 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) PHP/5.3.3-7+squeeze15 with Suhosin-Patch mod_python/3.3.1 Python/2.6.6 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

- The python error seems harmless (see [Python version mismatch, expected '2.6.5+', found '2.6.6'](https://serverfault.com/questions/445179/python-version-mismatch-expected-2-6-5-found-2-6-6)).
- The xdebug error is suspicious, but xdebug had been working well before my changes and seems to be ok:

*xdebug error seems to exist:*

```
root@debian:/home/brd# ls /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/ -al
total 1836
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Mar 13 15:29 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root   4096 Mar 12 17:07 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 866513 Mar 13 15:29 imagick.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 109220 Mar  4 09:23 mysqli.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  42352 Mar  4 09:23 mysql.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  26116 Mar  4 09:23 pdo_mysql.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  87588 Mar  4 09:23 pdo.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 141336 Aug 19  2010 suhosin.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 561230 Jul  8  2010 xdebug.so
```

**Apache seems to be running..**

```
root@debian:/home/brd# ps aux | grep apache
root      2338  0.0  0.6  45448 12696 ?        Ss   10:51   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  2346  0.0  0.3  45448  6536 ?        S    10:51   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  2347  0.0  0.3  45448  6536 ?        S    10:51   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  2348  0.0  0.3  45448  6536 ?        S    10:51   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  2349  0.0  0.3  45448  6540 ?        S    10:51   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  2350  0.0  0.3  45448  6536 ?        S    10:51   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
root      2358  0.0  0.0   3304   764 pts/0    S+   10:52   0:00 grep apache
```

*httpd listening on port 80?*

```
root@debian:/home/brd# ss -nal | grep 80
0      128                           :::80                           :::*
```

*check firewall*

```
root@debian:/home/brd# iptables -n -L -v
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

*'Listen' directives from /etc/apache2/ports.conf*
(there is no Listen directive in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf)

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    # If you add NameVirtualHost *:443 here, you will also have to change
    # the VirtualHost statement in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl
    # to <VirtualHost *:443>
    # Server Name Indication for SSL named virtual hosts is currently not
    # supported by MSIE on Windows XP.
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

**And yet..**

I still cannot ping port 80 from my windows machine.  From here, I don't know where to go.    Suggestions?

Comment: I fixed the formatting; apparently it gets confused when you use a code within a numbered list, so I added some headers in between.

Comment: Try to replace `Listen 80` with `Listen 192.168.1.222:80` and then `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this line when starting apache2:

> Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to

You need to have root privileges to start daemon, which binds to port number less than 1024.

Try `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start`

Comment: Thanks for the catch.  However, restarting as root doesn't help me reach port 80 from my windows machine.  See my edits above.

Comment: Check if `httpd` is listening port 80: `ss -nal | grep 80` or `netstat -atnl | grep 80`. And also check firewall: `iptables -n -L -v`

Comment: And yes, you cannot `ping` port, so "could not find host 192.168.1.222:80" would be forever - because there is no such host. Try to open it in browser ot `telnet 192.168.1.222 80` from `cmd.exe`

Comment: Added results of port and firewall checks, but they don't mean much to me..

Comment: Oh, I see. Everything is fine with the firewall, but your `apache2` is listening port 80 only on IPv6 wildcard address. You need to make it listening IPv4. Please add to your post the value of `Listen` directive from `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` or `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`.

Comment: OK, try to replace `Listen 80` with `Listen 192.168.1.222:80` and then `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

Comment: Did that and it works now.  The browser hung for ~2 minutes the first time, but now the site loads quickly and seems to work well. Can't imagine why this wasn't an issue earlier as I have never manually changed that directive...

Comment: When `apache2` starts, it tries to bind itself to any possible addresses port 80. If you start `apache2` when no IPv4 configured interfaces available, it might cause an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't stopped/started your Apache, as you were logged as normal user, or there's another web server running on port 80.

Comment: My goof.  Unfortunately restarting as root doesn't give me any leads - apache seems to be running fine on the VM